# How to flash success and danger with different messages in flask.

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application where I want to flash different alert messages depending on an action.

here is my first message, where i check if an email matches my regex pattern:

```
reciver = str(email)
if not re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", reciver):
    flash("Please enter a valid email address", 'error')
    return render_template("about.html")
```

here is the second message, which is displayed if a message is sent successfully:

```
flash('Message sent succesfully', 'succes')   
return render_template("about.html")
```

here is my HTML code:

```
      <h1 class="mb-5"> Enter your message, and i will get back to you as soon as possible</h1>
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-success">
            <li>{{ message }} </li>
         </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

how can I make an alert-danger for the first message and an alert-success for the second message, is there some sort of conditional that can be used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to specify the `category` parameter of the [`flash` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.flash).

> :param category: the category for the message.  The following values
>                        are recommended: `'message'` for any kind of message,
>                        `'error'` for errors, `'info'` for information
>                        messages and `'warning'` for warnings.  However any
>                        kind of string can be used as category.

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for category, message in messages %}
      <div class="alert {{ category }}"> {{ message|capitalize }} </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

By putting `category` in the class attribute, you can associate special colors with some css rules like :

```
.alert.success {
  background-color: green;
}

.alert.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

```
flash('Message sent successfully', 'success')
flash("Please enter a valid email address", 'error')
```

These calls will generate:

```
<div class="alert success">  Message sent successfully </div>
<div class="alert error">  Please enter a valid email address </div>
```

---

Official documentation : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/flashing/#flashing-with-categories

Answer (score 9):

With flask 1.0.2 this similar but slightly different approach worked for me - slightly simpler I think:

```
flash('This is an error message in red', 'danger')

flash('This is an informational message in blue', 'info')
```

In  Flask HTML template:

```
   {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
           <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}" role="alert"> {{ message }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

This way I didn't need to define any CSS and just used what was already in the default Flask distribution.